# Not being able to cast shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've made this table mesh which i would like to cast shadows on the pane(floor) mesh. I've been trying playing around with the ShadowMap for quite some while now but i cant seem to get it to work.

This is the current look:
[image]

**camera & scene**

```
 const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight), 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 8;
    camera.position.y = 2;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
```

**The table mesh**

```
    const boxWidth = 1; const boxHeight = 0.1; const boxDepth = 1;
    const tableBoardGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const customPicture = textureLoader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/resources/images/compressed-but-large-wood-texture.jpg')
    const tableBoardMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: customPicture, wireframe: false})
    const tableBoard = new THREE.Mesh(tableBoardGeometry, tableBoardMaterial)
    tableBoard.position.set(0, 0, 0)
    tableBoard.castShadow = true;
```

**The lightning & shadow**

```
    const lightAndShadow = () => {
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.75);
        const lightIntensity = 1.3; const lightDistance = 18;
        const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, lightIntensity, lightDistance);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1)
        light.castShadow = true
        light.target = tableBoard;
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
        light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, 1, 500, 1000))
        light.shadow.bias = 0.0001
        light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048*2
        light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048*2
        scene.add(light, ambientLight);
}
```

**The floor mesh**

```
const floorWidh = 20; const floorHeight = 20; const floorWidthSegments = 50; const floorHeightSegments = 50;
    const floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( floorWidh, floorHeight, floorWidthSegments, floorHeightSegments );
    floorGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
    const floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQOOcWSD0K2mPwokAFfZIhq5Xl49bh8B17RlU6NqCGa4UOKydgX');
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorTexture.repeat.set(20, 20);
    const floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: false}),
    floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
    floor.position.set(0, -tableLegHeightPosition, 0)
    floor.receiveShadow = true;
```

Any suggestions on how i can get the shadows to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assinging a new instance of `THREE.LightShadow` to `light.shadow` should not be necessary. Any reasons for doing this?

Comment: Just a confused developer. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Did you turn on shadows on the renderer itself? `renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;` see [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-shadows.html)

Answer (score 0):

`light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, 1, 500, 1000))`

You are overriding the default camera parameters of LightShadow and defining the `Near Clipping plane` to 500 which is making the `tableBoard` shadows to disappear.

You can reduce this number to the default of 0.5 or something near to it. Having the `near clipping plane` as 500 is a very big number for your case.

From the Docs:

> .shadow : LightShadow
>
> A LightShadow used to calculate shadows for this light.
>
> The lightShadow's camera is set to a PerspectiveCamera with fov of 90, aspect of 1, near clipping plane at 0.5 and  far clipping plane at 500.

Refer Three.js complete doc for Point light shadows [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/PointLight.shadow)